# Count the number of repetitions for one column

Tags: mysql

I am unable to successfully write this query and have not yet found any resources.

I have a table with two columns. The table looks a bit like this:

```
|student|teacher|
| 5314  | 656   |
| 4189  | 671   |
| 4506  | 671   |
| 4515  | 671   |
| 3754  | 756   |
| 3760  | 756   |
| 1066  | 781   |
```

I want the result set to look like this:

```
|teacher|count|
|  656  |  1  |
|  671  |  3  |
|  756  |  2  |
|  781  |  1  |
```

Any hint is really appreciated.

Comment: Good places to start reading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_function and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Queries

Comment: Are these two different tables?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html Look at the COUNT example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the COUNT(*) aggregate function here, and group by the teacher column.

Try this:

```
SELECT teacher, COUNT(*) as numStudents
FROM myTable
GROUP BY teacher;
```

This will group all rows from your table by teacher, and count the number of rows in that group (effectively counting the number of students).

Here is more on [Aggregate Functions](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_functions.asp) for you.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments.

Comment: Of course - a good answer should always come with an explanation, not just code to be copy and pasted. Feel free to give an upvote too, if it was that good ;)